# How to configure HAProxy according to request based on ports on same IP ?

Tags: nginx, redirect, haproxy, gateway

I Have Two Background server

Website-1. 192.168.1.10:80

Website-2. 192.168.1.10:8080

I have to use haproxy as gateway for accessing it through same URL, Difference is that website-2 access through Port No Putting it manually after ip.

( I want This Both on SSL, Http to HTTPS Redirections)
Haproxy IP : 192.168.1.11

Scenario 1.

client enters 192.168.1.10 it redirects to https:192.168.1.10

192.168.1.10 ---> https:192.168.1.10

Scenario 2.

client enters 192.168.1.10:8080 it redirects to https:192.168.1.10:8080

192.168.1.10:8080 ---> https:192.168.1.10:8080

How can i achieve This situations using Haproxy Or nginx

Comment: 192.168.1.11 ---> https:192.168.1.11 (backend 192.168.1.11)

192.168.1.11:8080 ---> https:192.168.1.11:8080 (backend 192.168.1.11:8080)

Comment: This question is also on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/q/830179/153161).  Please don't cross-post.